# Read space separated integers in PHP console

Tags: php

I am writing a console application in php, in which user will enter some integer value.

Sample Input - 21 5 2

For reading this values, I am using

```
fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $a);
fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $b);
fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $c);
```

But the value is only being assigned on variable a. How can I read all variable in corresponding variables.

Note: The integers can not be entered in different lines.

Comment: integers in input separated by space or by new-line?

Comment: Space separated is not working here. Inly first value is getting assigned on a. For rest I need to enter another value in a new line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d %d\n", $a, $b, $c);`.

Example:

```
<?php
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

print_r("Your 3 numbers:\n");

fscanf($stdin, "%d %d %d\n", $a, $b, $c);

print_r(sprintf('$a : %d $b : %d $c : %d' . "\n", $a, $b, $c));
```

If you need more information about format strings, you may want to take a look at the [php documentation for sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

If you want to parse more than jsut a few numbers or even a variable amount, you can pass only two arguments to `fscanf`. Then `fscanf` returns an array with all the parsed values.

```
<?php
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

print_r("How many numbers do you want to enter? :  ");
fscanf($stdin, "%d\n", $n);    

print_r("Your ". $n . " numbers:\n");

$result = fscanf($stdin, str_repeat("%d ", $n). "\n");

print_r("I have parsed " . implode($result, ", ") . "\n");
```

The output looks like this:

```
How many numbers do you want to enter? :  10
Your 10 numbers:
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55
I have parsed 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55
```

Comment: what if integers more than three?

Comment: You can just extend your format string with more integers `%d` and add arguments to `fscanf`

Comment: @kalehmann What if I have an array of n size and have to insert integers in that array? I mean if n is 5 then, I have to write %d five times, but n is a variable, which will be entered by the user.